# Acoustic guitar with pickup vs. semi-acoustic guitar

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, semi-acoustic-guitar, beginner

I ordered this guitar yesterday:

> Cort AD810E, Dreadnought Acoustic Guitar w/Cort CE304T Ceramic pickup

But due to the defect in their stock, they are offering me a

> Cort Ndxcq - Bk, 6 String Semi Acoustic Guitar

I want to know whether it is a good swap?

I would like to know the difference between these two in particular, or between semi-acoustic and acoustic-with-pickup in general terms.

Comment: Related: http://music.stackexchange.com/a/11505/12202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit too specific for this site, but since I looked into it I'll post an answer.

The guitar you ordered:

[image]

The guitar they offer as a replacement:

[image]

So it's quite different guitars, and I think that giving such a guitar in replacement is sort of dishonest of the store. The one you originally ordered is a quite standard model, while the replacement looks to be geared towards soloing and people used to electric guitars.

A general tip would be to try out the guitar before buying, and if possible buy second hand. Personally, I wouldn't deal with this shop again...

http://www.cortguitars.com/en/product/ad810e

http://www.cortguitars.com/en/product/ndx-cq

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you also tell what is the difference between semi acoustic and acoustic with pickup in general. Also please tell me whether second one will be a nice buy for a beginner to learn playing guitar.

Comment: "Semi-acoustic" is usually used to refer to hollow-body electrics (see e.g. [Epiphone Casino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphone_Casino)). "Electro-acoustic" is usually used to refer to acoustic guitars with integrated pickups. Both of these are electro-acoustics (and they **have the same pickup**, as well as spruce tops with mahogany neck and sides, which is perhaps why they've suggested the replacement).

Comment: @NishanthLawrence: It's hard to say. One thing to note is that the paint job on the replacement guitar might make it harder to sell, if you find that guitar isn't for you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Will there be any difference in the sound produced ? Also there won't be any problems for a beginner to start with semi acoustic right ?

Comment: I would expect some differences in unplugged sound, due to the different body shapes etc., but which is preferable is an issue of taste. And no, there is no particular issue with starting on an electro-acoustic (I did!)